# Where is the GridSplitter in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

I'm working on an app to try and get to grips with Windows 8. I want to add a `GridSplitter` to my XAML form, but the control doesn't seem to be available.

The XAML I have is

```
<Page
    x:Class="TweetiCon.BlankPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TweetiCon">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

but the `GridSpliter` element is causing the the app not to complile, because

> The name GridSplitter does not exist in the namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation

but I'm pretty sure it does. That's where it is in normal WPF applications.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this blog [post](http://blog.xyzzer.me/2012/01/16/gridsplitters-part-3-limiting-the-range-of-a-gridsplitter/)

> There is no GridSplitter on Windows Phone or in WinRT. I checked what MinWidth/MaxWidth do then (on Windows Phone and in WinRT) on a column with Width=”Auto” with variable size content and it seemed like while MinWidth did work to keep the column a given size – the column did stretch beyond MaxWidth, although the documentation says: “the MinWidth value takes precedence over the MaxWidth value, which in turn takes precedence over the Width value”.

The "documentation" begin referred to is this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.maxwidth%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

RE: *There is no GridSplitter on Windows Phone or in WinRT*
Indeed but not until now...
If you're searching for a GridSplitter you can have a look
WinRT.Xaml.Toolkit on CodePlex.

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

and look for **CustomGridSplitter** control.

I've tested the code in WinRT [both in RP and RTM] versions and it did the job.
You may give a try ;)

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with this project?